# What is the simplest way to interact between a SAP OMS and Websphere Commerce?

Tags: sap-basis, webmethods, websphere-commerce, wcs, adaptor

What is the simplest way to interact between a SAP OMS and Websphere Commerce?

Would it be using a Websphere Adaptor for SAP or webmethods or something else?

Does something else need to be considered while opting for one of these?

The final system needs to be synchronous between SAP and the WCS front end. No ques..no delays....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a combination of the SAP Business Connector (http://service.sap.com/sbc-download), which provides an easy interface for receiving/sending RFC calls from/to the SAP side, and the IBM WebSphere Java library, which allows easy interaction with WebSphere. ("webshphere.jar", can probably be found somewhere on http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere.)

In the Business Connector you can then write a "Java Service", which acts as a bridge between the RFC data from SAP and the WebSphere data. Should be only a couple of days development effort.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... there is a white paper from IBM's website that shows the best way for you to do this.   Depending on your IT strategy choose your integration pattern and integration technology.